# Programmatically add text to point on form with rotation

Tags: c#, text, drawing

I am trying to find a way to draw strings onto a specific point(X, Y) and a rotation angle. This sounds simple but I'm having real trouble getting my head around it.

I've been trying to figure out how to use drawstring to do this but while I have managed to get it to display the text, if I change the rotation angle the position changes too despite the position i'm telling it to draw at staying the same.

I've been messing around with it for a while now and so I was wondering if someone could explain how drawstring works? Please don't just give me a chunk of code, I actually want to understand whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can already draw the text I assume that you do that in the onpaint handler:

So:

```
// Copy Graphics object from EventArgs
Graphics g = e.Graphics;
// Save the current Matrix of the Graphics object
var currentMatrix = g.Save();
// Reset the Matrix to Identity matrix
g.Reset();
// Move the text Position to 0/0 
g.TranslateTransform(-textPosition.X, -textPosition.Y);
// Torsten in origin
g.RotateTransform(angle);
// Move Back the drawing point
g.TranslateTransform(textPosition.X, textPosition.Y);
// Draw text
g.DrawString(..);
// restore saved Matrix.
G.Restore(currentMatrix);
```

Bewahre this is pseudo Code, which must be improved by you. (I'm currently on my mobile).
I Hope I'm Not mistake with the sequence of instructions.

Merry X-Mas

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply. I got it working using your pseudo code. I had to swap the two lines "g.TranslateTransform(-textPosition.X, -textPosition.Y);" and "g.TranslateTransform(textPosition.X, textPosition.Y);""just for anyone reading this in the future. I've messed around with it a bit more now and i think i understand it. The matrix is like a surface you render the text through onto the form, and this is what you are rotating, rather than the text. Is this correct?